# Can I invert the Green channel of a Normal map in Blender?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, normal-map

Is it possible to invert the **green channel** for a normal map directly on Blender (without using nodes)? I'm exporting a mesh from blender to unity and the normal i imported gives me problem of color.